# Run script on windows startup with environment variable

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Windows should run a script on startup that starts a DB based on an environment variable `%SAPSYSTEMNAME%`:

```
net start SYBSQL_%SAPSYSTEMNAME%
```

When i run this command in my cmd it works fine, however on windows startup it will be ignored somehow and the db is not started.

I entered the script in `gpedit.msc` under Startup scripts.

Why is this so? timeout 120 also did not help - is there an alternative?

Comment: Is %SAPSYSTEMNAME% a user or system variable? It might not be available during startup because the userprofile with its variables didn't start yet.

Comment: @RicardoBohner yes the %SAPSYSTEMNAME% is a system variable. I also tried a simple echo %SAPSYSTEMNAME% > c:\out.txt but only the file is created without content, thus the variable cannot be read i assume.

Comment: Also do note that it may not be able to start the service because it is dependend on another service that must be started first. To make sure its a variable thing, test it with a hardcoded name and see if it starts at all. You know, as a test.

Comment: @LPChip i tried to print out only the variable in a simple text file. It did not give any result, thus it guess its not based on the service order.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to use the variable, my solution is silly but should work.

Go STRAIGHT TO THE KEY!! :)

`if "%SAPSYSTEMNAME%"=="" for /f "tokens=3" %%v in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"  /V SAPSYSTEMNAME') do Set SAPSYSTEMNAME=%%v`

Place that line before `net start SYBSQL_%SAPSYSTEMNAME%`

Ugly as heck but should do the trick.